# Erro gradle Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 5.1.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\PROJECTS_FLUTTER\Stickers\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is pretty explicit, and everything is written to fix it.

```
Edit the distributionUrl in E:\PROJECTS_FLUTTER\Stickers\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip
```